# Why is this scriptlet code being shown on HTML page?

Tags: html, jsp, scriptlet

[image]

For the code given below, I have this `value="">` being shown on the HTML page as shown above. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
<td class="data" align="left" valign="middle" width="80%">
    <input type="text" name="CMD" size="20" maxlength="16"
    <% if ( retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber.length() > 0 ){%>
        value="<%=retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber%>">&nbsp;
    <%}else{%>
        value="">&nbsp;
    <%}%>
</td>
```

HTML as seen on the page running it

```
<td class="data" align="left" valign="middle" width="80%">

    <input type="text" name="CMD" size="20" maxlength="16">

    value="">&nbsp;

</td>
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with different server versions. This code is running on WAS 8.5 server but when it runs on WAS 6.1, the `value="">` is not shown on the page. Strange!

**Update:**

There was nothing wrong with the above code. It was a WebSphere issue which was picking up the older version of the file. Rebuilt and redeployed and it was all good!

Comment: Can you show the actual output HTML rather than what the browser is trying to do with it?

Comment: @Brad added code as on page.

Comment: There is a `>` after maxlength="16". This is closing the tag and treating everything between that and `</td>` as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there was nothing wrong with the above code. It was a **WebSphere issue** which was *picking up the older version of the file*. I rebuilt and redeployed and it was all working fine!

Answer (score 1):

I never suggest you to use **Scriptlet** in JSP instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) that is more easy to use and less error prone.

Try with JSTL first:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:if test="${ retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber.length()  > 0}">
    <td class="data" align="left" valign="middle" width="80%">
         <input type="text" name="CMD" size="20" maxlength="16" value="${retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber}"/>
    </td>
</c:if>
```

As per your code first calculate the value and then finally use it in `value` attribute to make it more clear.

```
<%
    String value = "";
    if (retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber.length() > 0) {
        value = retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber;
    }
%>

<td class="data" align="left" valign="middle" width="80%">
     <input type="text" name="CMD" size="20" maxlength="16" value="<%=value%>"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Braj, what I am looking at is a legacy code and it's like 2000 lines of similar code, so I don't think refactoring is feasible until absolutely necessary. But I will try modifying it as per your suggested approach.

Comment: what about second option?

Comment: Yes, I am modifying as per that. I will let you know after I have edited and tested it. :)

Comment: again you are mixing html with Scriplet.

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to modify minimally. I thought maybe by assigning the `value` earlier I can remove the `else` condition which for some reasons is not rendered correctly.

Comment: Well, I tried your JSTL approach. It did not help! I still see `value="">` on the page.

Comment: For some reasons the page is not refreshing on server..any ideas why??

Comment: How come I know without any exception details?

Comment: Well, there is no exception. It's just that the old page is being displayed..I have restarted the jvm..let's see..

Comment: Ok, there is this tag error: `JSPG0068E: Unmatched tag found while parsing jsp [c:if]`. I have this code in html file which gets included in a jsp file. Can you tell me where to define the taglib?

Comment: Have you included `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` in your JSP file.

Comment: Yes, I did. Do I need to include the taglib into HTML file? Or define it in web.xml?

Comment: you need `jstl.jar` place it under WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Read it here [How do I use JSTL on my JSPs?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-jstl-on-my-jsps.html)

Comment: I already have jstl-1.0.2.jar!! Can't access that page at my company..Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Doesn't require anything else. Just a import in JSP. If you are still facing an issue then please follow a tutorial. I'll share you some more.

Comment: Read here [Set up JSTL for JSP 2.x](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/SetupJstlForJsp2) and here [Installing JSTL support](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073217/soa/jsp-standard-tag-library-eases-webpage-development.html)

Comment: Sorry one thing that I missed to tell you. You require some TLDS and place it directly under WEB-INF/tld folder. Download it from the above mentioned links.

Comment: Oh man, it did not work so I undid the whole thing and switched back to the original code. I figured out it was a WebSphere cache issue. Redeployed and it was all good. I can't mark this as an answer but I will +1. Thanks for helping me out..

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional operator like mentioned below.

```
<input type="text" name="CMD" size="20" maxlength="16" 
    value="<% = retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber.length() > 0 ? retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber:"" %>" />
```

hope it should work

Comment: semicolon is not allowed in the end with assignment Scriplet `<%=`

Answer (score 0):

You've got something closing your input tag automatically.  Notice you have printed out `<input type="text" name="CMD" size="20" maxlength="16"` on one line then you're trying to print the rest in the if-statement, one another line.  Something's closing it before you do. What, I have no idea.  But you could try printing it all as one line.

```
<td class="data" align="left" valign="middle" width="80%">
<%
   String value = "";
   if ( retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber.length() > 0 )
   {
      value = "" + retrieveXMLCommand.cmdNumber;
   }
   out.print("<input type='text' name='CMD' size='20' maxlength='16' value='" + value + "' />&nbsp;");
%>
</td>
```